# Difficulties to understand series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Hi in my book there is a series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \cdot \frac{1}{n}$$

the context is convergence and so on. And this series serves as an exampel for a not absolut convergent but convergent series. For me it looks like the harmonic series, which clearly diverges:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$$=$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\frac{1}{n}|$$

Am I wrong?

Comment: $\frac 1n$ is always positive, but $(-1)^n$ alternates negative, positive, so the even terms and odd terms partially cancel out.\

Comment: hm i thought taking the absolute value of a negative number equals positive number

Comment: $\frac{(-1)^n}{n} = -1, \frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{4},\dots$ while $\frac{1}{n}$ has no negative numbers.

Comment: Googi, we look at the absolute value of the general term of a series **only** to test for absolute convergence. And in this case, testing for absolute convergence yields the harmonic series, which diverges. For this reason, your series is **not absolutely convergent.** But then, we need to test for non-absolute convergence, which is not determined only by the absolute value of the general term. What you have is an *alternating series* (see your text, or the link in my answer), which may converge precisely because the terms of the series alternate between positive and negative.

Comment: I understand. I mixed up absolute convergence vs. convergence. One imply the other but not vice versa.so  algebraically I´m correct, however not conceptually :-)

Comment: Yes, $$\text{absolute convergence} \implies \text{convergence}.$$ But *be careful*: It is **not true** that if a series fails to be absolutely convergent, it then fails to be convergent. $$\text{Not absolutely convergent} \require{cancel} \cancel{\implies} \text{Not convergent}$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When we test for absolute convergence, you are correct, you have the harmonic series, which does not converge. Hence, your series is **not absolutely** convergent.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left|(-1)^n \cdot \frac{1}{n}\right| = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac 1n$$

But your series is **not equal to** the harmonic series, since the terms alternate between positive and negative. Because of this, and for other reasons, while NOT *absolutely* convergent, $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \cdot \frac{1}{n} = -1 + \frac 12 - \frac 13 + \frac 14 - \cdots $$ is convergent, and we can make this conclusion using the *[**alternating series test.**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test)*

---

When you have an *alternating series*, like this one, where the terms alternative between positive and negative

- First we check if a series is *absolutely convergent*. If so, we are done. Absolute convergence guarantees convergence.
- If a series is not absolutely convergent, we must then check for
  (non-absolute) convergence, using the alternating series test (also sometimes called Leibniz's Test).

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{(-1)^n}n\ne\left|\frac1n\right|$ if $n$ is odd.